# square inscribed in a right triangle

Tags: geometry

[image: Here is the figure]    A square of maximum possible area is circumscribed by a right angle triangle ABC
    in such a way that one of its side just lies on the hypotenuse of the triangle.
    What is the area of the square?
    actually the answer is given as
 $(abc/(a^2+b^2+ab))^2$
    Please provide the approach to solve the problem.

Comment: Presumably, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the sides of the triangle, with $c$ being the hypotenuse?

Comment: Seems to me (draw a picture!) that there are several triangles similar to ABC, and you should be able to get some mileage from that.

Comment: @dtldarek i extended the triangle into a rectangle. and the square also. Then i used $1/2*d_1*d_2$ and the final answer as $ab/4$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson is the answer $ab/4$ wrong?

Comment: got the answer ! answer - (abc/(a^2+b^2+ab))^2 . Answer is a bit lengthy, will comment it soon !!

Comment: @lsp Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I don't understand how you extend the triangle and square, and I don't know what you mean by $d_1$ and $d_2$. Also, you haven't answered my question about the meanings of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson now i edited my question with clear explanation of a,b,c.Could you solve or provide the easy approach to solve.

Comment: My approach, as I already commented, is to note how many similar triangles there are in the picture (and use standard facts about similar triangles). But I see you already have some answers, so I don't need to go into any more details.

Comment: to be honest this is really hard way of explaining im studying in year 8 to get a good mark in year9 and i need some basics of Squares Inscribed in a Right Triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider - a,b as right legs and c as the hypotenuse.

Let side of square = s
AC = b, BC = a, AB = c.

[image: Right Angled Triangle]

FB = as/b and AE = bs/a as the colored triangles are similar to the bigger triangle.

Steps to calculate area `(S^2)` :

1)Calculate GB and AD using right angle triangle rule for triangles GBF and ADE.

2)Calculate GD using right angle triangle rule for triangle GCD.

3)`GD^2` = `s^2`. You get a quadratic equation in s which can be factorized. You get s = (abc)/(a^2 + b^2 +a.b)

If still not clarified will post the answer then.

Comment: how you got FB=as/b

Comment: i got $FB=bs/a$ and $EA=sa/b$ and please post the clarification.

Comment: sry you are correct.. i just wrongly used the ratio. FB=as/b is correct.And thanks for the answer. I got it.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$\hspace{60pt}$[image: hint]

The red solid line is the height dropped onto the hypotenuse, i.e. $h = \frac{ab}{c}$ and the red dotted lines are of the same length. The green parallel lines are unnecessary, but might get you some intuitions.

Good luck! ;-)

Comment: how to get $h=ab/c$. which pair of similar triangles to consider for that.

Comment: @cdummy $P_{\triangle ABC} = \frac{1}{2}ab = \frac{1}{2}ch$.

Comment: I appreciate your answer from my heart. But the problem is i need some simple solution. or a hard one that is explained. See your reputation is 6340, where as mine is 29. i m sry to say this i cant get your point of approach. Can u give a detailed solution only if u are interested...

Comment: @cdummy Well, I don't have time to write a fully detailed answer, but consider the following. First calculate the area of the triangle in two ways: $\frac{1}{2}ab = |\triangle ABC| = \frac{1}{2}ch$ to get $h = \frac{ab}{c}$. Let $x$ be the side of a square, then the picture implies (the black and gray triangles are similar) that $\frac{x}{c} = \frac{h}{c+h}$, so $$x = \frac{ch}{c+h} = \frac{c\frac{ab}{c}}{c+\frac{ab}{c}} = \frac{abc}{c^2+ab}.$$

Comment: @cdummy $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle, so [$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). To get the final answer, the area of a square with side $x$ is [$x^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square#Perimeter_and_area).

Comment: yeah great help. Now I understand ur whole solution for the problem. This is the simple way to solve it.

Comment: @dtldarek great answer !!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: 
The square formed some similar right-angled triangles, make use of the ratio of the sides.

Comment: Much as I noted earlier, in one of my comments.

Answer (score 0):

The question can be easily solved by subtracting the two sides of a right triangle from the bigger triangle
i.e. subtract 'as/b' and 'bs/a' from the hypotenuse of larger triangle 'c'.and it will be equal to the side of a square.
S=c-(as/b+bs/a).
And thus s=abc/a^2+b^2+ab

Comment: Use MathJax and format your post for making your answer better.