# Proving that a line is an angle bisector

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, quadrilateral

> In a right triangle $\triangle ABC$ with  $A=90^{\circ}$ we inscribe a square which one side of it is located on hypotenuse $BC$. Prove that the line which joins vertex $A$ to the center of square is angle bisector of angle $A$.

My attempt: if we call the center of square $O$ we have to prove angle $BAO$ and the angle $CAO$ are $45^{\circ}$.

Comment: Your “attempt” is just a restatement of the problem.

Comment: @dxiv In the question, a side of the square is on the hypotenuse. Presumably your *"vertex of the square on the hypotenuse"* means where the extension of $AO$ meets $BC$ and you are looking at another square

Comment: @Henry Right, thanks for pointing out. Comment removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of the inscribed square. 
Moreover let $D$ be the vertex of the square along $AB$ and let $E$ be the vertex of the square along $AC$.
Then $DE$ is parallel to $BC$ and, by the [law of sines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320367/square-inscribed-in-a-right-triangle) applied to the triangles $\triangle ADO$ and $\triangle AEO$, we have that 
$$\frac{|DO|}{\sin(DAO)}=\frac{|AO|}{\sin(B+45^{\circ})}
=\frac{|AO|}{\sin{(C+45^{\circ}})}=\frac{|EO|}{\sin(EAO)}$$
where the second equality holds because $B+C=90^{\circ}$. Note that $|DO|=|EO|$, hence it follows that $\sin(DAO)=\sin(EAO)=\cos(DAO)$, that is  $DAO=EAO=45^{\circ}$.

Comment: How come you have equated law of sines of two different triangles?

Comment: @max Law of sines explains the first and the third equality. The second equality follows from the fact that $\sin{(B+45^{\circ}})=\sin{(C+45^{\circ}})$ since $B+C=90^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be the center of the square $PQRS$, where $P\in AB$ and $Q\in AC$.

Thus, $DPAQ$ is cyclic and since $PD=QD$, we obtain $$\measuredangle DAP=\measuredangle DAQ$$ and we are done!

Comment: @ Rozenberg what do you mean by cyclic? Would you refer me to an article or something Please!

Comment: It means that there is a circle, which passes trough  points  $D$, $P$, $A$ and $Q$. Because $\measuredangle A+\measuredangle PDQ=180^{\circ}.$